# Under what conditions will the two shell commands below not create the same contents "text_files.txt"?

Tags: linux

1. ls *.txt > text_files.out
2. ls *.txt >& text_files.out

My answer is when there are one or more files with the ".txt" extension in the directory

Comment: Don't just post a question here from a homework assignment. Have you actually done any research or tried anything on your own?

Comment: Why is your answer that?

Comment: If  you look up the difference between `>` and `>&`, the answer should be close by.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Difference between `>` and `>&` :

- `>` will redirect stdout to a file
- `>&` will redirect both stdout and stderr to a file

Therefore when an error occurs, `ls *.txt > text_files.out` will output nothing to `text_files.out` but `ls *.txt >& text_files.out` will output the error message to `text_files.out`.

Answer (score 0):

when no files called *.txt can be found the result will be different.

Comment: This depends on the shell though.  There would be no difference if using `zsh` for example.

Comment: the only other possible answer is in a race condition when the user loses permission to read the directory after creating the output file. seems unlikely.